# A dynamic form with unique names

Tags: jquery, html, forms, user-input

I have a form where a user can dynamically add more fields.

Example:

```
<form>
  <input name="school" type="text" />
  <input name="degree" type="text" />
  <button role="button">Add another school</button>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, I would like to add 2 more inputs for another school & degree. Easily doable with jQuery.

**What should I set for the new `name` attributes?** When I submit this form I want unique school & degree pairs.

Comment: I've considered iterating like "school1" "school2" etc. But this will require extra logic to put all of this into an array, and so on. Hoping there is a cleaner way with just HTML cleverness.

Comment: You can change the input `name` attribute programatically as you add the new lines by keep a count of how many new lines you have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make them an array....

```
<form>
  <input name="school[]" type="text" />
  <input name="degree[]" type="text" />
  <button role="button">Add another school</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Noted should be that this is not specific to HTML, but to PHP! It is actually a hack in order to distinguish parameters with multiple values  from those with single value, so that PHP can as being a weak typed language based on parameter name figure when to return an array or not. Other (strong typed) languages like JSP do not need those ugly bracelets.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a hidden input the saves the count of the pairs

And when you click the button, you add new pair with name postfixed by the count ex:"school[i]", then increase the count..

And on the server-side, you read the count input then you loop from 0 to count-1 to read the pairs

**Check this code**
http://jsfiddle.net/2jdmP/

```
<form>
  <input name="pair_count" id="pair_count" value="1" type="hidden" />
  <p>
    <input name="school0" type="text" />
    <input name="degree0" type="text" />
  </p>  

  <button role="button" id="add_button">Add another school</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_button').click(function(){

        var pair_count = $('#pair_count');
        var count = parseInt( pair_count.val() );

        $(this).before(' <p><input name="school'+ count +'" type="text" /> <input name="degree'+count+'" type="text" /> </p>')
        pair_count.val( count+1 );

        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Why would you create an HTML element just to save something like an iterator count? Why not just use js

Comment: @DonnyP to submit the count value with the form to server-side script, check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can always count the existing nodes and create new ones.
Assuming the base fieldset to have an id `qual`
The following code can do the job:

```
var nextIndex = $('#qual > fieldset').length+1;
var next_row='<fieldset id="pair'+nextIndex+'"><input type="text" name="school'+nextIndex+'"/><input type="text" name="degree'+nextIndex+'"/></fieldset>';
$('#qual').append(next_row);
```

You can view the working example on js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hunkyhari/4QUXz/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can

```
<input name="school[]" type="text" />
<input name="degree[]" type="text" />
```